# php create file in directory

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The below code checks for a directory 'dat'; if it ins't there, it creates one. That part works just fine; what I need is for it to write a file to said directory where AJAX can read it from.

Here's the php...

```
//checks for 'dat' directory; if false, creates it, if true, does nothing.
$dir = 'c:\wamp\www\dat';
if(file_exists($dir)){
return;
}
else{
mkdir ('C:\wamp\www\dat',0700);
}
//writes chats to file
$data = fopen($dir. "/chatlog". date('d'). '.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($data, $speak);
fclose($data);
}
```

And here's the AJAX; I don't need as much help here as I do above, but I won't complain if you provide the help for the AJAX below, mainly in getting it to read from the file within the 'dat' directory...

```
xhr.open("GET","chatlog<?php /*stamps the chatlog file with date (numerical day only)*/ echo     date("d");?>.txt",true);
```

Comment: In what directory this PHP script is ?  It seems like your are just having some mistakes with the paths. You are not creating the file inside the directory *dat*...

Comment: I think that your backslash escaping is wrong! it should be ` \\ ` i.e `C:\\Path\\to\\any\\location`

Comment: @sємsєм the backslash escaping doesn't change anything, file still isn't created.

Comment: @VitorLima The script is being run in the www directory; www/dat is where the file should be created. I simply don't know how to create the file inside the directory.

Comment: Use absolute paths: `fopen('c:\\wamp\\www\\dat\\chatlog' . date('d') . '.txt', 'a+');`

Comment: @Ja͢ck that doesn't reslove it either...but it does clean things up a bit! :D

Comment: You should check the `fopen()` warning for clues then.

Comment: @Ja͢ck the error can't be in fopen(); this whole process worked fine when it wrote the file to the www directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script is running inside *www*, then, your file you be created there.

If you want to create the file inside the directory *www/dat*, just change this line

```
$file = "chatlog". date('d'). ".txt";
```

for this one

```
$file = 'dat\chatlog'. date('d'). '.txt';
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it either; I've updated the code above.

Comment: Maybe it's because I had wrote '/' instead of '\'.